# RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception') django haystack

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack, drf-haystack

I am trying to use django-haystack with djangorestframework and elasticsearch and followed the tutorial [here](https://drf-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I have installed the following packages in my virtual env

```
djangorestframework==3.5.4
drf-haystack==1.6.1
elasticsearch==1.5.0
```

### Haystack settings

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'drf',
    'haystack',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

But whenever i tried to rebuild_index as `python manage.py rebuild_inex` or whenever i tried to retrieve the results using an API at `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/location/search/?city=Hyderabad`, i am getting the below error and i have googled much about this but couldn't able to get any help

```
Failed to query Elasticsearch using 'city:(Hyderabad)': TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/ipitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 524, in search
    _source=True)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/ipitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/ipitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 504, in search
    params=params, body=body)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/ipitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/ipitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 89, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/Users/shivakrishna/.virtualenvs/ipitch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception')
```

I have read some where that the above error will be because of elasticsearch version more than 2.0.0,but i have installed 1.5.0 and still i am facing above error.

Can anyone let me know how to solve this ?

Comment: I am going through the same problem. Have you found out the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has some dependencies when it comes to Django-Python. Please install pyelasticsearch with which all the dependencies such as urllib3, elasticsearch and more will be installed.

Make sure that elasticsearch version is 1.x.y (2.x.y can do as well) after the installation otherwise downgrade the elasticsearch to <2.0.0, which you can do from `requirements.txt` or otherwise.

Additionally, please check and post the result of query on `http://127.0.0.1:9200/` as this would show the version of elasticsearch you've on your system. I think this should be the issue as the log which you have attached shows errors related to version issues, which I was also facing for few days.

More importantly, have you started the elasticsearch server? Check the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/running-elasticsearch.html) for this as well.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I have tried downgrading the elasticsearch but the error remains the same.